# The transformation of Gamma matrices under charge cojugation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, charge-conjugation

Consider the Dirac field theory. In this theory the transformation of charge conjugation on a Dirac field is given by,

$U(C) \psi(x) U(C)^{-1} = \eta_c C \psi^*(x)$,

please note the $C$ give on RHS is Gamma matrix related to charge conjugation. Suppose we don't know what $C$ is. So in order to determine it we can demand that the Dirac equation,

$(i\gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}  - m)\psi(x) = 0$

remains invariant under the charge conjugation transformation. How does this condition leads to the equation,

$U(C) \gamma^{\mu} U(C)^{-1} = -{\gamma^{\mu}}^*$?

Why are we not taking the following equation? Is it because we get contradiction in majorana basis?

$U(C) \gamma^{\mu} U(C)^{-1} = {\gamma^{\mu}}^*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the finite size matrix $C$ that acts on the spinor indices with the infinite-dimensional charge conjugation operator $U(C)$ that acts on the infinite dimensional Hilbert space. The operator $U(C)$ would obey
$$
U(C)  \gamma^\mu U(C)^{-1}=\gamma^\mu
$$
because $U(C)$ sees $C$ as an array of numbers and therefore commutes with it.

What you need is
$$
C\gamma^\mu C^{-1} =-\gamma^T.
$$
For a discussion of all thise see my [arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.00518) that was written as a long answer to a stack exachange question similar to yours